# How to trigger action before url in <browser> will be loaded?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm trying execute some action before a specified url will be loaded in `<browser>` element. `<browser>` can be sidebar or in a tab.

Example: (context is browser main window):

```
// it can be also browser of tab
var browser = document.getElementById("sidebar"); // <xul:browser>

// execute a function when window of browser will be prepared for loading new content but before any script will be executed
execOnWindowPrepared(browser, function(window) {
    // e.g. inject something
    window.foo = "bar";
});

// load an uri 
browser.loadURI("chrome://foo/content/bar.xul"); // (can be also http:)
```

Note I can't execute my action immediately after `loadURI` statement because `browser.contentWindow` will still point to old window.

Perhaps [progress listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener) can be used for this but I'm confused for which flags I need wait.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [content-document-global-created or document-element-inserted notification of nsIObserverService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications). Which one you use depends on what your script is doing. If it's just setting window-level variables as in your example, content-document-global-created would be best. If you need to insert elements or otherwise have the `<html>` element available, document-element-inserted would be better.

document-element-inserted is the method [that Greasemonkey uses](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/aa7e9bffd30b1a8f6eea11e0dd987f909535b3b0/components/greasemonkey.js#L310) when you include @run-at document-start.

Comment: Thanks. content-document-global-created has one limitation. Its location.href [may not be final url yet](http://bugzil.la/800677). Now, I'm using another solution that uses progress listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I ended with using such approach. It was coded by trial and error and so may be wrong with some cases but I didn't noticed any problems with many tests.

```
// opens aUrl in aBrowser and call an action defined in aCallback immediately after window is prepared
function loadInBrowserWithCallback (aBrowser, aUrl, /* function(window) */ aCallback) {
    var loadedUrl = nsIIOService.newURI(aUrl, null, null).spec // canonify chrome url (what mean 'canonifing': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChromeRegistry#canonify%28%29 )
    var lastWindow = aBrowser.contentWindow;
    lastWindow.__thisIsPrevWin = true;
    var progressListener = { 
        onLocationChange : function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aLocation, aFlags) { 
            var window = aWebProgress.DOMWindow;
            if(!window.__thisIsPrevWin && window.location.href === loadedUrl) {
                // the property assigned to previus window was removed and location.href isn't any transitional url
                aBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
                aCallback(window);
            }
        },
        onProgressChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aCurSelfProgress, aMaxSelfProgress, aCurTotalProgress, aMaxTotalProgress) {
            var window = aWebProgress.DOMWindow;
            if(!window.__thisIsPrevWin && window.location.href === loadedUrl) {
                aBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
                aCallback(window);
            }
        },
        onSecurityChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aState) {
            var window = aWebProgress.DOMWindow;
            if(!window.__thisIsPrevWin && window.location.href === loadedUrl) {
                aBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
                aCallback(window);
            }
        },
        onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
            var window = aWebProgress.DOMWindow;
            if(!window.__thisIsPrevWin && window.location.href === loadedUrl) {
                aBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
                aCallback(window);
            }
        },
        onStatusChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus, aMessage) {
            var window = aWebProgress.DOMWindow;
            if(!window.__thisIsPrevWin && window.location.href === loadedUrl) {
                aCallback(window);
                aBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
            }
        },
        QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
            if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
                aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
                aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
                return this;
           throw Cr.NS_NOINTERFACE;
        }
    };
    aBrowser.addProgressListener(progressListener, Ci.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_ALL);
    aBrowser.loadURI(aUrl);
};
```